# Metacity: Remove title bar from XTerm windows and true maximize

Tags: gnome, window, title-bar, metacity

In IceWM I can tell XTerm windows to have no title bar and be truly maximized in `~/.icewm/winoptions`:

```
xterm.XTerm.dTitleBar: 0
xterm.XTerm.startMaximized: 1
```

With "truly maximized" I mean, that the

```
XTerm*maximize: true
```

-Option in `.Xresources` doesn't really maximize the window in terms of window managers, but expands a minimized window to desktop width.

The question is: Can I have the IceWM behaviour in **Metacity** as well? Any XTerm (and only XTerm) being on startup

- maximized, and
- without title bar

Compiz can be tricked to do that with the ccsm. But as long as [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xterm/+bug/644943) isn't fixed, I'm stuck to Metacity.

I just read about [Devil's Pie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie). Can it be done without it? I don't want necessarily to run the devilspie server only for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, pretty sure you have to use Devilspie.

Something like this should do it:

```
(if
    (is (window_class) "Terminal")
    (begin (undecorate) (maximize)))
```

You could even go one step further and maximize all windows using this rule:

```
(if
    (is (window_property "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE") "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL")
    (begin (undecorate) (maximize)))
```

If you don't want to use Devilspie, you could replace Metacity with Openbox, which supports the feature you want.

Just put

```
<applications>
<application class="Gnome-terminal">
  <maximized>true</maximized>
  <decor>no</decor>
</application>
<application class="Terminal">
  <maximized>true</maximized>
  <decor>no</decor>
</application>
</applications>
```

in the middle of your ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml.

Or you could try [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) instead of Devilspie.

Comment: I also note that the bug you mention is now fixed in Compiz.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought so, too. Indeed, on one machine I meanwhile switched to Compiz, again. On the other I'm bound to metacity, have a restrictive quota and don't have admin rights. I'll have to live with the border :-(